# Disabling clustering on Jboss

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

We have a single node running Jboss 6.1 AS and want to disable clustering/HA totally. The main reason is that we see lot of UDP packets being sent on 230.0.0.4 (guess that is for auto discovery of nodes?).

Thanks in advance.